# Python Polar Heat map 0 and 2pi convergence

Tags: python, heatmap

Good evening.

I have the following python code below for plotting a polar heat map based upon pasting thickness values corresponding to R/theta locations

I'm trying to determine if I need to repeat the value at 0 or 2pi to make the plot converge correctly or if there is something else I can do.

Code is below

```
import libraries
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

z=input("paste the z values from One Note")

#print(z)

thick = [float(num) for num in z.split()]

radius = [500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,250,250,250,250,250,250,250,250,0]

theta = [1.570796327,
         0.785398163,
         6.283185307
,
         5.497787144,
         4.71238898,
         3.926990817,
         3.141592654,
         2.35619449,
         1.570796327,
         0.785398163,
         6.283185307
,
         5.497787144,
         4.71238898,
         3.926990817,
         3.141592654,
         2.35619449,
         6.283185307
]

#print (len(theta))

data = [radius,theta,thick]

rad = data[1]
azm = data[0]
z = data[2]

plt.subplot(projection="polar")
plt.tricontourf(rad, azm, z, levels=256, cmap='coolwarm')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Plot is below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQMyk.png)